# Interpretation of regression tree with Poisson data

Tags: regression, cart, poisson-regression

[image: ter]

Above is a decision tree made by following code

```
tree1 <- rpart(cbind(EMP_HRS_TOTAL/2000, NUM_INJURIES) ~ . - EMP_HRS_TOTAL - INJ_RATE_PER2K,
                      data = train,
                      method = "poisson",
                      control = rpart.control(minbucket = 25, 
                                              cp = .05, 
                                              maxdepth = 10))
```

My question is

1. I do not understand why left side of the formula is "cbind" form. Can it just be Number of injuries?
2. It seems like that predictions made by this tree is injury rate instead of number of injuries. What does "cbind" do to this tree ?
3. How can I interpret the number below each prediction number (for instance 0.045 is prediction by this tree, what does 5802/819 mean?)

Comment: Could you please provide more background of your data? E.g., which variables are involved, how are they called and what do they stand for?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick trip to the help function for rpart, rpart.plot(), and rpart.text I think I can answer your questions.

1. I notice that you cbind hours worked and number of injuries. Normally Poisson regression is done to find a rate (#events/time or #events/obs). Are all observations equal time periods? If so then you may not need the hours. If not then you need something to control for time worked, which seems to be what that hours part is doing...
2. See (1). If you are trying to predict how often an injury occurs obs then you probably don't need the hours worked, but you should be wary of this approach since one would expect there to be some rate for injuries occurring.
3. If you read the documentation it says that for Poisson regression the format is "the number of events/number of observations"